# using first() in laravel fractal

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to transform on the first item of Contacts and here is my code

```
public function includeContact(Customer $customer)
{
    return $this->item($customer->contacts()->first(), new ContactTransformer);
}
```

but it's not working and I get this error : 
Type error: Argument 1 passed to

> App\Transformers\ContactTransformer::transform() must be an instance
>   of App\Models\Contact, null given, called in
>   *\vendor\league\fractal\src\Scope.php
>   on line 407

**Edited**
Here is ContactTransformer

```
namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Models\Contact;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class ContactTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Contact $contact)
    {
        return [
            'value' => $contact->value,
            'type' => $contact->communication->title,
            'icon' => $contact->communication->icon
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is CustomerTransformer

```
class CustomerTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    protected $availableIncludes = ['contacts', 'contact'];

    public function transform(Customer $customer)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $customer->id,
            'name'=>$customer->name,
            'status' => $customer->status,
            'tags' => $customer->tags->pluck('name'),
            'created_at' => Verta::instance($customer->created_at)->format('Y/n/j'),
        ];
    }

    public function includeContacts(Customer $customer)
    {
        return $this->collection($customer->contacts, new ContactTransformer);
    }

    public function includeContact(Customer $customer)
    {
        return $this->collection($customer->contacts, new ContactTransformer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a null value  when you `dd($customer->contacts()->first())` ?

Comment: No, I get an Instance

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share your `ContactTransformer` code in your question?

Comment: I've Just added

Comment: Where is `includeFirstContact` method defined?

Comment: It is defined inside **CustomerTransforemer**. Post edited

Comment: Register 'firstContact' in [`$availableIncludes`](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/#including-data) or [`$defaultIncludes`](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/#default-includes)

Comment: I changed the first contact to contact

Answer (score 0):

It's because some of your customers don't have contacts. Looks at your `ContactTransformer` class on `transform()` method, it should receive instance of `Contact`. If you give that method `null`, of course it'll fail.

Then, you need to have like so,

```
class ContactTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Contact $contact = null)
    {
        if (is_null($contact)) return null;

        return [
            'value' => $contact->value,
            'type' => $contact->communication->title,
            'icon' => $contact->communication->icon
        ];
    }
}
```